# What do you achive by using this code?

Tags: javascript, dictionary, html-table, easeljs, createjs

I'm currently working on a tower defense game, and I'm currently in the process of implementing the different towers. And I'm lookin for a way to set up predefined values like a config file which I can extract the different values for the different towers on build time.

I've been searching around a bit and I came across a bit of code that looks like this:

```
var  building_attributes  =  {
        "Wall" :  {
            Damage :  0 ,
            RANGe :  0
            speed :  0
            bullet_speed :  0
            life :  100 ,
            Shield :  500 ,
            cost :  5
        }
 };
```

If I implemtented this, how can I then access the different values? Or perhaps someone out there has a good solution to my problem.

All answers are much appreicated. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For example, accessing `life`:

```
var life = building_attributes.Wall.life;
//live === 100
```

`building_attributes` is a variable containing an object, with a `Wall` property. The `Wall` property is another object with properties. Properties of objects are accessible via [the dot-notation, bracket notation or combination of both](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4968406/575527).

If you have gone through a data structures course, this structure of organizing data is called a *tree*. It's when one piece of data has children, which can be data or subtrees. These subtrees can also contain data, or subtrees and so on.